# Adobe PDF Embed API - > ViewerAPI-> gotoLocation() not changing the page

Tags: adobe, adobe-pdfservices

We used the PDF embed API to view the PDF on an angular page and used the gotLocation() method to move to a particuler page after PDF loaded. I used the below code as mentioned in the https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/how-to-open-pdf-with-jump-to-particular-page-in-embed-adobe-api/td-p/384277

```
pdfFilePromise.then(adobeViewer => {
          console.log('file rendered')
          if (this.item.pageId) {
            console.log('opening page', this.item.pageId)
            adobeViewer.getAPIs().then((apis: any) => {
              apis.gotoLocation(this.item.pageId)
                .then((data) => {console.log("Page opening Success");
                   console.log(data) })
                .catch((error: any) => console.log('Page opening error', error));
            });
          }
}
```

The PDF loading successfully, but not going to the given page. Even I am getting "data" value as "true" in the **then** function of the **gotoLocation**() method and printing "Page opening Success" in console. But PDF is not moving the given page. Always showing the first page.

It works fine from last 3 months, but today it stopped suddenly.  It stopped working in all environments even we deployed any thing from last 1 month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue fixed after they rolled back the last version. please check the comments in below link for answer

https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-services-api-discussions/pdf-embed-api-gt-viewer-api-gt-gotolocation-method-stopped-working-suddenly/m-p/14487380